# why i can not convert JSON (GSON) date format to java object from retrofit request body?

Tags: java, android, json

I am sending request body to server (backed by JAVA/JERSEY/JACKSON) from Android (Retrofit). I im logging request body through interceptor and it looks like something

```
{"workId":"456655","workName":"some work","workOrderDate":"Jan 29, 2020 12:00:00 AM"}
```

On server side My `Project` object is able to parse every field except `"workOrderDate"`. I tried to change Gson date format of various type using

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .create();`

but still in JSON the format is unchanged (Jan 29, 2020 12:00:00 AM) and it is not assigning to `"workOrderDate"`field of `Project` object on server side.

Object on Servier side-

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "project_id")
private Integer projectId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 200)
@Column(name = "work_name")
private String workName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "work_description")
private String workDescription;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "consignee_work_order")
private String consigneeWorkOrder;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "work_order_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date workOrderDate;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "consignee")
private String consignee;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "sent_by")
private String sentBy;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "chargeable_head")
private String chargeableHead;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "account_unit")
private String accountUnit;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "fund_exist")
private String fundExist;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "fund_certificate")
private String fundCertificate;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "approx_cost")
private Double approxCost;
@Column(name = "approx_weight")
private Double approxWeight;
@Size(max = 200)
@Column(name = "drawing")
private String drawing;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "required_at")
private String requiredAt;
@Lob
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "remark1")
private String remark1;
@Lob
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "remark2")
private String remark2;
@Lob
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "remark3")
private String remark3;
@JoinColumn(name = "division", referencedColumnName = "division_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Division division;

public Project() {
}

public Project(Integer projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

public Project(Integer projectId, String workName, String workDescription, String consigneeWorkOrder, Date workOrderDate, String sentBy) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
    this.workName = workName;
    this.workDescription = workDescription;
    this.consigneeWorkOrder = consigneeWorkOrder;
    this.workOrderDate = workOrderDate;
    this.sentBy = sentBy;
}

public Integer getProjectId() {
    return projectId;
}

public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

public String getWorkName() {
    return workName;
}

public void setWorkName(String workName) {
    this.workName = workName;
}

public String getWorkDescription() {
    return workDescription;
}

public void setWorkDescription(String workDescription) {
    this.workDescription = workDescription;
}

public String getConsigneeWorkOrder() {
    return consigneeWorkOrder;
}

public void setConsigneeWorkOrder(String consigneeWorkOrder) {
    this.consigneeWorkOrder = consigneeWorkOrder;
}

public Date getWorkOrderDate() {
    return workOrderDate;
}

public void setWorkOrderDate(Date workOrderDate) {
    this.workOrderDate = workOrderDate;
}

public String getConsignee() {
    return consignee;
}

public void setConsignee(String consignee) {
    this.consignee = consignee;
}

public String getSentBy() {
    return sentBy;
}

public void setSentBy(String sentBy) {
    this.sentBy = sentBy;
}

public String getChargeableHead() {
    return chargeableHead;
}

public void setChargeableHead(String chargeableHead) {
    this.chargeableHead = chargeableHead;
}

public String getAccountUnit() {
    return accountUnit;
}

public void setAccountUnit(String accountUnit) {
    this.accountUnit = accountUnit;
}

public String getFundExist() {
    return fundExist;
}

public void setFundExist(String fundExist) {
    this.fundExist = fundExist;
}

public String getFundCertificate() {
    return fundCertificate;
}

public void setFundCertificate(String fundCertificate) {
    this.fundCertificate = fundCertificate;
}

public Double getApproxCost() {
    return approxCost;
}

public void setApproxCost(Double approxCost) {
    this.approxCost = approxCost;
}

public Double getApproxWeight() {
    return approxWeight;
}

public void setApproxWeight(Double approxWeight) {
    this.approxWeight = approxWeight;
}

public String getDrawing() {
    return drawing;
}

public void setDrawing(String drawing) {
    this.drawing = drawing;
}

public String getRequiredAt() {
    return requiredAt;
}

public void setRequiredAt(String requiredAt) {
    this.requiredAt = requiredAt;
}

public String getRemark1() {
    return remark1;
}

public void setRemark1(String remark1) {
    this.remark1 = remark1;
}

public String getRemark2() {
    return remark2;
}

public void setRemark2(String remark2) {
    this.remark2 = remark2;
}

public String getRemark3() {
    return remark3;
}

public void setRemark3(String remark3) {
    this.remark3 = remark3;
}

public Division getDivision() {
    return division;
}

public void setDivision(Division division) {
    this.division = division;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (projectId != null ? projectId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Project)) {
        return false;
    }
    Project other = (Project) object;
    if ((this.projectId == null && other.projectId != null) || (this.projectId != null && !this.projectId.equals(other.projectId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.nrbwlko.officeprojectmaven1.Project[ projectId=" + projectId + " ]";
}
```

}

Android side

```
public class PojoProject {
private Integer projectId;
private String workName;
private String workDescription;
private String consigneeWorkOrder;   
private Date workOrderDate;
private String consignee;
private String sentBy;
private String chargeableHead;
private String accountUnit;
private String fundExist;
private String fundCertificate;
private Double approxCost;
private Double approxWeight;
private String drawing;
private String requiredAt;
private String remark1;
private String remark2;
private String remark3;
private PojoDivision division;

public PojoProject(String workName, String workDescription, String consigneeWorkOrder, Date workOrderDate, String consignee, String sentBy, String chargeableHead, String accountUnit, PojoDivision division) {
    this.workName = workName;
    this.workDescription = workDescription;
    this.consigneeWorkOrder = consigneeWorkOrder;
    this.workOrderDate = workOrderDate;
    this.consignee = consignee;
    this.sentBy = sentBy;
    this.chargeableHead = chargeableHead;
    this.accountUnit = accountUnit;
    this.division = division;
}

public Integer getProjectId() {
    return projectId;
}

public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

public String getWorkName() {
    return workName;
}

public void setWorkName(String workName) {
    this.workName = workName;
}

public String getWorkDescription() {
    return workDescription;
}

public void setWorkDescription(String workDescription) {
    this.workDescription = workDescription;
}

public String getConsigneeWorkOrder() {
    return consigneeWorkOrder;
}

public void setConsigneeWorkOrder(String consigneeWorkOrder) {
    this.consigneeWorkOrder = consigneeWorkOrder;
}

public Date getWorkOrderDate() {
    return workOrderDate;
}

public void setWorkOrderDate(Date workOrderDate) {
    this.workOrderDate = workOrderDate;
}

public String getConsignee() {
    return consignee;
}

public void setConsignee(String consignee) {
    this.consignee = consignee;
}

public String getSentBy() {
    return sentBy;
}

public void setSentBy(String sentBy) {
    this.sentBy = sentBy;
}

public String getChargeableHead() {
    return chargeableHead;
}

public void setChargeableHead(String chargeableHead) {
    this.chargeableHead = chargeableHead;
}

public String getAccountUnit() {
    return accountUnit;
}

public void setAccountUnit(String accountUnit) {
    this.accountUnit = accountUnit;
}

public String getFundExist() {
    return fundExist;
}

public void setFundExist(String fundExist) {
    this.fundExist = fundExist;
}

public String getFundCertificate() {
    return fundCertificate;
}

public void setFundCertificate(String fundCertificate) {
    this.fundCertificate = fundCertificate;
}

public Double getApproxCost() {
    return approxCost;
}

public void setApproxCost(Double approxCost) {
    this.approxCost = approxCost;
}

public Double getApproxWeight() {
    return approxWeight;
}

public void setApproxWeight(Double approxWeight) {
    this.approxWeight = approxWeight;
}

public String getDrawing() {
    return drawing;
}

public void setDrawing(String drawing) {
    this.drawing = drawing;
}

public String getRequiredAt() {
    return requiredAt;
}

public void setRequiredAt(String requiredAt) {
    this.requiredAt = requiredAt;
}

public String getRemark1() {
    return remark1;
}

public void setRemark1(String remark1) {
    this.remark1 = remark1;
}

public String getRemark2() {
    return remark2;
}

public void setRemark2(String remark2) {
    this.remark2 = remark2;
}

public String getRemark3() {
    return remark3;
}

public void setRemark3(String remark3) {
    this.remark3 = remark3;
}

public PojoDivision getDivision() {
    return division;
}

public void setDivision(PojoDivision division) {
    this.division = division;
}
```

}

Method to trigger call to server side from ViewModel -

```
public void save() {
    System.out.println(workDate.getValue());
    Date workorderDate = getWorkDateFromString(workDate.getValue());

    PojoProject project = new PojoProject(workName.getValue(), workDescription.getValue(), workOrder.getValue(), workorderDate, consignee.getValue(), sentBy.getValue(), chargeableHead.getValue(), accountUnit.getValue(), selectedDivision.getValue());


    projectRepository.saveProject(project);

}
```

Here is my serverside Rest End Point where i am collecting JSON into `Project()` Object and persisting to database --

```
@POST
@AnnotationSecured
@Path("saveProject")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
// @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void saveNewProject(Project newProject) {
    System.out.println("inside save new project");
    if (newProject.getWorkOrderDate() == null) {
        System.out.println("date is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("date is  " + newProject.getWorkOrderDate().toString());
    }
    Project project = null;
    EntityManager em = UtilityJPA.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        em.persist(newProject);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    } finally {
        em.clear();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show the class that has those 3 fields.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using `gson-2.8.5.jar`. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @andreas information updated

Comment: [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Andreas please specify what you want, I am stuck since many days , applied all the solution i was able to get on stackflow. I need help bro.

Comment: We need a **Minimal** piece of code that reproduces the problem you have, i.e. using Gson created like you showed to generate the JSON you showed, but getting the date format wrong, generated from some object with a lot fewer fields than 19, since the JSON only has 3, and not needing 4-5 different classes to **Reproduce** the problem. **Minimal** code, as already stated. --- When I created a class with just the 3 fields shown in the JSON, initialized them with those values, and generated JSON using a `Gson` created like shown, the JSON had the requested date format. Hence: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: @andreas then why i am getting date null on server side? i have posted server side end point. Using jackson with jersey.

Comment: Your question was about not getting date in the requested format. That has nothing whatsoever to do with "null on server side". Don't change the question. If you have a different question, create a new question. ***This*** question is about the date format in the generated JSON text. Please provide [**Minimal**, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing code where you get JSON generated with the date format you showed, even though a different format was specified in the `GsonBuilder`. --- *"jackson with jersey"* No, **Gson** not Jackson!

Comment: @andreas my question is not about json format but it is about why i am not getting it from JSON to java object. I found the answer,  it is because Jackson is not recognizing my date format inside JSON, i changed the JSON Date format to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' and now its is working. but i still appreciate you if you can elaborate this answer.

Comment: @Rafa If you have found the fix, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `DateFormat.FULL`. It works fine for me like this

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL).create();
```

Comment: Still same Date format inside json Request body {'"workOrderDate":"Jan 31, 2020 12:00:00 AM"}' and serverside workOrderDate field is null other fields are OK.

Comment: Can you update your question with complete code where you are converting the json to java object?